# How to set css class of a label in a django form declaration?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm using django-uniform and to use some uniform features, I'm looking for a way to add css class directly from form declaration (for independents widgets).

(as a bonus, here my reusable read-only home made mixin snippet...)

```
from django import forms

def _get_cleaner(form, field):
    def clean_field():
        return getattr(form.instance, field, None)
    return clean_field

class UniformROMixin(forms.BaseForm):
    """
    UniformROMixin, inherits to turn some fields read only

      - read_only = list of field names.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UniformROMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(self, "read_only"):
            if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
                for field in self.read_only:
                    self.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
                    self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] += "readOnly"
                    # here I would like to set css class of the label
                    # created from the self.fields[field].label string
                    setattr(self, "clean_" + field, _get_cleaner(self, field))
```

My only way for now is to add a bit of javascript on my generic form template and add classes manualy.

Any brillant idea?

Comment: I don't know of a way to add a css class in the form declaration, but I've used: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks to conveniently add attributes to things like label tags and form elements at the template level when it makes sense to do so.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion. In my case I don't handle the template part fully done by django-uniform. I still can see how works the "render" method of the widget and override it...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Widgets have an `attrs` keyword argument that take a `dict` which can define attributes for the input element that it renders. Forms also have some attributes you can define to change how Django displays your form. Take the following example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
    my_field = forms.CharField(max_length=10,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'my_field',
                                                             'class': 'my_class'}))
```

This works on any `Widget` class. Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to change how Django renders labels if you just do `{{ field }}`. Luckily, you play with the form object a little bit in the template:

```
<form>
    {% for field in form %}
        <label class="my_class" for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then again, you can always add arbitrary attributes to the objects you're working with:

````
# In a view...
form = MyForm()
form.label_classes = ('class_a', 'class_b', )
# Or by hijacking ```__init__```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_field = forms.CharField(max_length=10,
                                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'my_field',
                                                                      'class': 'my_class'}))
        self.my_field.label_classes = ('class_a', 'class_b', )
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
````

Render your template with the form in context, and in the template you can do:

```
<form>
    {% for field in form %}
        <label class="{% for class in field.label_classes %}{{ class }} {% endfor %}"
               for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Whatever suits your fancy.

Comment: Excellent solution! Just the first line for those trying to use it should be `{% for field in form.myfield %}`

Comment: `Field` objects are not iterable

Comment: @xj9: How would this work ina ModeForm? When I ty access it like self.field it throws a error, when i add a attribute to self.fields[field] it doesn't show up ...

Comment: label_class do not exist n Dango 4.0

Answer (score 6):

I found this snippet which may be a good answer:

[How to add css class and "*" to required fields's labels](https://thebitguru.com/blog/908-adding-to-required-fields)

here an adaptation to my needs (not tested yet, I'll edit the post once done):

```
from django.utils.html import escape

def readonly_cssclass_adder(bound_field, label_content, label_attrs):
    if 'readonly' in bound_field.field.widget.attrs:
        if 'class' in attrs:
            label_attrs['class'] += " readOnly"
        else:
            label_attrs['class'] = "readOnly"
    return label_content, label_attrs
        

def add_required_label_tag(original_function, tweak_foos=None):
    if not tweak_foos:
        return original_function

    def required_label_tag(self, contents=None, attrs=None):
        contents = contents or escape(self.label)
        if attrs is None:
            attrs = {}
        for foo in tweak_foos:
            contents, attrs = foo(self, contents, attrs)
        return original_function(self, contents, attrs)
    return required_label_tag

def decorate_bound_field():
    from django.forms.forms import BoundField
    BoundField.label_tag = add_required_label_tag(BoundField.label_tag, 
                                           tweak_foos=[readonly_cssclass_adder])
```

If you have a better solution which don't tweak all the BoundField class I'm still listening.

edit:
may be linked to django uniform way to handle required field but it seems to don't call `readonly_cssclass_adder`. But I found an other and easyer solution, my readOnly widget automatically turned readOnly ctrlHolder

This addition is my favorite response for now:

edit 2: The other way I choose at end was to "override" the `uni_form/field.html` template which don't call BoundField.label_tag. So I checked here field state.

```
<label for="{{ field.auto_id }}"{% if field.field.required %}
       class="requiredField{% if field.widget.attrs.readonly %} readOnlyLabel{% endif %}"
       {% else %}{% if field.widget.attrs.readonly %}class="readOnlyLabel"{% endif %}{% endif %}>
    {{ field.label|safe }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}
</label>
```