# Django 1.9 adding a class to form label

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-1.9

In my forms.py file I reconfigured the class UserForm's `__init__` function to include a css class. Unfortunately doing this only allowed me to add a class to the `<input>` and not the `<label>`. How can I add a class to the label as well?

Here is my forms.py file:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control'
        }

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not email:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please enter an email address.')
        if User.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email "%s" is already in use.' % email)
        return email
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you not target this form element from an external css file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add class to Django label\_tag() output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414679/add-class-to-django-label-tag-output)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959178/how-to-set-css-class-of-a-label-in-a-django-form-declaration

You could do something like this:


<form>
    {% for field in form %}
        <label class="my_class" for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Answer (score -3):

Look at [Django Widget Tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks/).

Comment: Please give answers to the questions instead of pointing modules that do it for them.