# Django Form Field Custom attribute assignment and use in template

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to generate a form dynamically and want to assign indentation of form fields. I am trying to assign an custom attribute ***offset*** to forms.CharField in subclass. I plan to use this logic to create a form dynamically from an xml file, where the fields would be indented based on the depth of the node.

I am unable to retrieve the value of offset while rendering the template and hence unable to assign the margin-left style parameter. The final html output is also shown.

Can someone please help. I have searched some other answers on this site where it appears that arbitrary attributes can be assigned and retrieved in template. e.g.[as in thread here where an arbitrary label_class attribute is assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959178/how-to-set-css-class-of-a-label-in-a-django-form-declaration)

My forms.py file :

```
class MyCharField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.offset = kwargs.pop('offset', 0)
        super(MyCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class MyDynamicForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["Field_A"] = MyCharField(label="Input A", offset="5")
        self.fields["Offset_Field_B"] = MyCharField(label="Input B", offset="50")
```

My Views.py looks like this:

```
class MyDynamicView(View):
    template_name = 'demo/myform.html'
    form_class = MyDynamicForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

My template file using bootstrap looks like this:

```
{% extends 'demo/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block content %}
    <form role="form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group bootstrap3-required">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label " style = "margin-left: {{field.offset}}px" for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label}}</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input class="form-control" id="id_{{field.name}}" name="{{ field.name }}" placeholder="{{field.label}}" style="margin-left:{{field.offset}}px" title="" required="" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}  
        {% buttons submit='OK' reset='Cancel' layout='horizontal' %}{% endbuttons %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The html output is:

```
<form role="form" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='lTy0rc2r9KNiNNPosUoriUlNzYBpgoVpael1MYLOczFECO7H7LXdES6EGBhUoXx0' />


    <div class="form-group bootstrap3-required">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label " style = "margin-left: px" for="Field_A">Input A</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control" id="id_Field_A" name="Field_A" placeholder="Input A" style="margin-left:px" title="" required="" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group bootstrap3-required">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label " style = "margin-left: px" for="Offset_Field_B">Input B</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control" id="id_Offset_Field_B" name="Offset_Field_B" placeholder="Input B" style="margin-left:px" title="" required="" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">&#160;</label><div class="col-md-9"><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">OK</button> <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Cancel</button></div></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It not necessary to instantiate from CharField for that. Probably such initialization of the field in form will be enough for you:

```
  field_a = forms.CharField('Input_A',
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input_A', 'style': 'margin-left: 50px'}))
```