# Django-crispy-forms: set css for individual field and inputs

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

Is there a way to specify the css for an individual field and input in django crispy forms?  I am using bootstrap4 and would like to use a horizontal form for a few fields in my form.

I know you can use a self.helper to set label.class and field.class but I presume that applies to all field. I only want to change the label and field class on a few of my fields.

**EDIT:**

I need to add css to the label that is different from the input

I'm trying to get a horizontal field inside a form like the amount field below

[image]

```
<div id="div_id_amount" class="row">
    <label for="id_amount" class="col-form-label col-2  requiredField">
        Amount<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="">
        <input type="number" name="amount" step="0.01" class="numberinput form-control col-md" required="" id="id_amount">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at [layouts](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html). Or you can just set class attributes for the [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances) of a field. Both links show you examples where the class of the input element is changed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new at this and having a hard time reading through the docs.  I basically want to make a horizontal form and have read I need to specify a col-* size for the id and input field and wrap that in a row div.  But I don't know how to specify two sizes for 1 element. Does that make sense?

Comment: I usually advise against using crispy-forms because it moves the layout into the `Form` code and I believe layout should be done in HTML. The second link tells you that if you add `name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'col-6'}))` to a `name` field in your form your input field will have `col-6` as class attribute.

Comment: Anyway, the documentation is well written and "having a hard time reading through the docs" usually means "I can't be bothered". Sorry, but without reading and understanding the documentation you won't get anywhere.

Comment: No no, I get that, believe me this is a last resort I have been looking for answers for about a week now.  what attrs would you use to set the css for the label? I guess that is what i'm struggling with.  I appreciate the assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556195/1252711):

- You add the class attributes for the input field via the widget, as also explained in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances)
- You explicitly add the `<label>` tags with the correct class in your HTML.

Or, for the label, you can also create the following template filter:

```
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def label_with_classes(field, css):
    return field.label_tag(attrs={'class': css})
```

which you can use like this in your template after you've loaded it with `{% load my_filters %}`: `{{ form.name|label_with_classes:"col-sm-6 col-lg-3" }}`

I don't know of an easy way with crispy-forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your Layout:

`Field('password', id="password-field", css_class="passwordfields", title="Explanation")`

You can find more details [here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#layout-objects)

Comment: That would set the css for the div containing both the label and the input correct? Is there a way to set the css for the label and the input separately?