# How to add a class to a field tag in a Django form

Tags: css, django, forms, bootstrap-4, label

I would like to add a bootstrap class to a label of the input field of my form, I can add classes to the input field but I could not find a guide on how to add a class to the label in the form declaration, can you help me? Thanks

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
file = forms.FileField (label="Choose File", widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True, 'class': 'custom-file-input'}))
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959178/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the label in your template.
For example,

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}" class="class-label">Title</label>
       {{ form.title }}
   </div>
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I can't because I'm using {{form | crispy}}, anyway i solved it with boostrap 5 thanks to the .form-control class